# If you want to remove an object from the first array which is not present in second array

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, find

If you want to remove more than one object from the first array "arrayOne" which is not present in the second array "arrayTwo". It's just a suggestion the way I do. If you have any other way please let me know.

```
let arrayOne = [{
          id: 1
        }, {
          id: 2
        }, {
          id: 3
        }]
        let arrayTwo = [{
          id: 2
        },{
          id: 3
        }]

for (var index = arrayOne.length; index--;) {
if (!arrayTwo.find(y => y.id === arrayOne[index].id)) {
  arrayOne.splice(arrayOne.findIndex(z => z.id === arrayOne[index].id), 1)
  console.log("After splice", arrayOne)
}
```

Comment: might wanna use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead

Comment: Please clarify your question, give example

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to store ids of elements of `arrayTwo` and then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to extract only those elements of `arrayOne` that are also present in `arrayTwo`:

```js
let arrayOne = [{
  id: 1
}, {
  id: 2
}, {
  id: 3
}];

let arrayTwo = [{
  id: 2
}];

let arrayTwoSet = new Set(arrayTwo.map(e => e.id));
console.log(arrayOne.filter(e => arrayTwoSet.has(e.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.some()` inside `Array.filter()`

```js
let arrayOne = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }] ;
let arrayTwo = [{ id: 2 }];

const result = arrayOne.filter(obj1 => !arrayTwo.some(obj2 => obj1.id === obj2.id));

console.log('final array : ', result);
```